# trying to build nodejs application written in typescrip return error with socket.io

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io

I have a simple node.js API was written in typescript.

however, when I try to run my build. it return me an error as

```
   node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket.d.ts:63:39 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

   63 export declare type Event = [eventName: string, args: any[]];
                                     ~

   node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket.d.ts:63:53 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

   63 export declare type Event = [eventName: string, args: any[]];
```

It looks like something wrong with the socket.io. it is because the socket.io version is not compatiable with the typescript version?

here is my package.json

```
"name": "project",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
 "tsc": "tsc",
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
 "start": "npx ts-node app.ts",
 "start1": "npm run build && node build/index.js",
 "dev": "nodemon ./src/app.ts",
 "dev1": "ts-node-dev --respawn ./src/app.ts",
 "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
 "express": "^4.17.3",
 "socket.io": "^4.4.1",
 "uuid": "^8.3.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
 "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
 "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
 "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
 "ts-node": "^10.5.0",
 "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
 "typescript": "^3.9.10"
}
}
```

I am running my build using

```
rimraf ./build && tsc
```

Answer (score 0):

change the typescript to 4.4.2 in package.json file and it works....I didn't know the package version is not same as my local..super mistake..